# How do I accept an expired ssl certificate with Apache client?

Tags: java, android, ssl

I'm trying to make `DefaultHttpClient()` work with expired SSL certificate.

```
Android API 2.2
```

It won't compile because of this line:

**SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(sslContext);**

Error: `The constructor SSLSocketFactory(SSLContext)` is undefined

What am I doing wrong?

```
    import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
    import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
    import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
    import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
    {...}

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");

        // set up a TrustManager that trusts everything
        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
                    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                            System.out.println("getAcceptedIssuers =============");
                            return null;
                    }

                    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs,
                                    String authType) {
                            System.out.println("checkClientTrusted =============");
                    }

                    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs,
                                    String authType) {
                            System.out.println("checkServerTrusted =============");
                    }
        } }, new SecureRandom());

        SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(sslContext);
        Scheme httpsScheme = new Scheme("https", sf, 443);
        SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
        schemeRegistry.register(httpsScheme);

        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        ClientConnectionManager cm = new SingleClientConnManager(params, schemeRegistry);

        //DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(cm, params);
```

Comment: Independently of how to pass this `SSLContext` to the HTTP client, what you're doing wrong is that you're using a trust manager that doesn't do anything to check the server certificate. These pass-through trust managers will let *any* certificate through (including those from potential MITM), not just the ones you trust but have expired.

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the documentation for [SSLSocketFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html), there doesn't appear to be a constructor:

```
SSLSocketFactory(javax.net.ssl.SSLContext)
```

The available constructors are:

```
SSLSocketFactory(String algorithm, KeyStore keystore, String keystorePassword, KeyStore truststore, SecureRandom random, HostNameResolver nameResolver)
SSLSocketFactory(KeyStore keystore, String keystorePassword, KeyStore truststore)
SSLSocketFactory(KeyStore keystore, String keystorePassword)
SSLSocketFactory(KeyStore truststore)
```

Am I missing something here?

See also [javax.net.ssl.SSLContext](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLContext.html)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't do anything wrong (except perhaps using some standard Java code).

It appears that the Android implementation of the Apache [SSLSocketFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html) class does not implement all the constructors of the original Apache [SSLSocketFactory](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html) class

You'll just have to improvise.